# Searching for a standalone JSP compiler

Tags: java, jsp, compiler-construction

I'm searching for a tool, which compiles a JSP file into a Java file without using a servletcontainer like Tomcat or something else. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: [jsp Runner](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsprunner/?source=directory) or this [link](https://dz.prosyst.com/pdoc/mToolkit/um/com.prosyst.tools.userdoc/doc/jsp_tool.html) helped me.

Answer (score 5):

There is an [ant task](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.html) that is shipped with tomcat that precompiles the jsps:

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat mentions Jikes as another compiler, but it looks like it is no longer maintained.

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Using%20Jikes
- http://jikes.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Jikes was a Java compiler, not a JSP compiler.